# Perl search is only showing last result

Tags: perl, search

I have two arrays, one with search terms and another which is multiple lines fetched from a file. I have a nested foreach statement and am searching for for all combinations, but only the very last match is showing even though I know for a fact that there are many other matches!! I have tried many different versions of the code but here is my last one:

```
open (MYFILE, 'searchTerms.txt');
open (MYFILE2, 'fileToSearchIn.xml');

@searchTerms = <MYFILE>;
@xml = <MYFILE2>;

close(MYFILE2);
close(MYFILE);
$results = "";

foreach $searchIn (@xml)
{
    foreach $searchFor (@searchTerms)
    {
        #print "searching for $searchFor in: $searchIn\n";
        if ($searchIn =~ m/$searchFor/)
        {
            $temp = "found in $searchIn \n while searching for: $searchFor ";
            $results = $results.$temp."\n";
            $temp = "";
        }
    }
}

print $results;
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `grep`: `grep -f searchTerms.txt fileToSearchIn.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, and declare all variables at the point of their first use using `my`. This applies especially when you are asking for help with your code as this measure can quickly reveal many simple mistakes.

As Raze2dust has said it is important to remember that lines read from a file will have a trailing newline `"\n"` character. If you were checking for *exact* matches between a pair of lines then this wouldn't matter, but since it's not working for you I assume the strings in `searchTerms.txt` can appear *anywhere* in the lines of `fileToSearchIn.xml`. That means you need to use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the strings from `searchTerms.txt`; lines from the other file can stay as they are.

Things like this are made a lot easier by using the [`File::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSlurp) module. It does all the file handling for you and will chomp any newlines from the input text if you ask.

I have changed your program to use this module so that you can see how it works.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;

my @searchTerms = read_file('searchTerms.txt', chomp => 1);
my @xml = read_file('fileToSearchIn.xml');

my @results;

foreach my $searchIn (@xml) {
  foreach my $searchFor (@searchTerms) {
    if ($searchIn =~ m/$searchFor/) {
      push @results, qq/Found in "$searchIn"\n while searching for "$searchFor"/;
    }
  }
}

print "$_\n" for @results;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the details, I will install the module and try it out

Comment: This worked :) but i had to do somehting silly, since I copied those two files from windows into linux, I simply created new linux based text files on linux and simply copies and pasted the content from the windows text files to the linux ones, saved those files and searched on the new linux created files and it worked :) thanks everyone

Comment: You can use [`PerlIO::eol`](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlIO::eol) to make your program work on any line ending. You need to install it but there is no need for a `use` line. Then you can write `open my $fh, '<:raw:eol(LF)', 'searchTerms.txt' or die $!` and then everything will appear to have Unix line terminators. You can slurp from this file handle using `read_file($fh, chomp => 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`chomp` your inputs to remove newline characters:

```
open (MYFILE, 'searchTerms.txt');
open (MYFILE2, 'fileToSearchIn.xml');

@searchTerms = <MYFILE>;
@xml = <MYFILE2>;

close(MYFILE2);
close(MYFILE);
$results = "";

foreach $searchIn (@xml)
{
    chomp($searchIn);
    foreach $searchFor (@searchTerms)
    {
        chomp($searchFor);
        #print "searching for $searchFor in: $searchIn\n";
        if ($searchIn =~ m/$searchFor/)
        {
            $temp = "found in $searchIn \n while searching for: $searchFor ";
            $results = $results.$temp."\n";
            $temp = "";
        }
    }
}

print $results;
```

Basically, you are thinking you are searching for 'a', but actually it is searching for 'a\n' because that is how it reads the input unless you use `chomp`. It matches only if 'a' is the last character because in that case, it will be succeeded by a newline.

Comment: When using chomp in this case you will want to make sure that the input record separator is set to the actual line separator style of 'searchterms.txt'. For example, if 'searchterms.txt' was generated on a Windows box, it will have line separators set to '\r\n'. If you are then running your script on a box which uses '\n' style line separators, the record separator will be set to '\n' by defualt, so `chomp` will leave `\r` characters at the end of each line, and you'll still be stuck with search terms which don't match.

Comment: hmmm I already tried chomp but didnt solve the problem, I tried it again the way you recommended and still no solution... so I will check perhaps it is leaving \r\n Ill try and fix thatby removing the \r first

Comment: Ok I replaced all \r\n with \n on all files and its actually worse now :) its not finding any results :D

Comment: @khaled You should post some sample input. And you should try the `grep` I posted in a comment above. You may have meta characters in your search terms which is causing mismatches. Also, since you are not using strict and warnings, and not checking the return value of your `open` statements, you could be suffering from a host of problems of which you know nothing.

Comment: @khaled In that case, check for the newline character. Were these files saved in Windows or Unix? Because the code I posteed works for me (Mac/Unix). Anyway, the best way, as TLP said, is to use grep. But if you want do this in this way, you can also try replacing all \r and \ns with empty strings first instead of chomp, to be sure.

Comment: Thank you I will post that now

Comment: @khaled, you don't want to replace `\r\n` with `\n`, you want to remove either `\r\n` or `\n`, depending on what's at the end of each line in your file. When I was talking about `input record separator` I was actually referring to the Perl special variable `$/` aka `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`. This variable controls what is removed by  `chomp()`.

Comment: grep is not working... and the files were saved from windows but I am programming from linux.... and you mentioned "you can also try replacing all \r and \ns with empty strings first instead of chomp" so this is what i did and is not returning any results

Comment: Try using the dos2unix (http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) command first on both files in that case, and then try the chomped version.